# How do I set REMOTE_USER in a HTTP header?

Tags: apache, http, authentication, header

I've got an issue with my Apache settings.

I installed a web application that partly accepts external authentication:

- I use Apache to manage the access to my application web pages.
- If the authentication is successful, the environment variable REMOTE_USER is set with the user's name.
- Then the user name is passed to my application through the HTTP header so the application opens on the user session.
- This is mostly an Apache configuration for the application. I only set the name of the variable (HTTP header) that contains the username in my application config file.

Here is the issue : I can authenticate successfully (most of the time) but my HTTP header is set to null.

Some additional details :

- I use Apache and the mod_perl modules (AuthenNIS + AuthzNIS + Net-NIS) to authenticate to my app with NIS account.
- With the following Apache config file I have the authentication form  when I try to access my application but the REMOTE_USER header is set to null.

  ```
      Listen 2208
      <VirtualHost *:2208>

                  RewriteEngine on
                  DocumentRoot "/path/to/static"


                  <Directory "/path/to/static">

                              Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                              AllowOverride None
                              Order allow,deny
                              Allow from all


                              AuthType Basic
                              AuthName "Authentifiez vous"
                              PerlAuthenHandler Apache2::AuthenNIS
                              PerlAuthzHandler Apache2::AuthzNIS
                              PerlSetVar AllowAlternateAuth no
                              require valid-user

                  </Directory>


                  RewriteEngine on
                  RewriteRule . - [E=RU:%{LA-U:REMOTE_USER}]
                  RequestHeader set REMOTE_USER %{RU}e

                         RewriteRule ^/apps$ /apps/ [R]
                         RewriteRule ^/static/style/(.*) /path/to/static/june_2007_style/blue/$1 [L]
                         RewriteRule ^/static/scripts/(.*) /path/to/static/scripts/packed/$1 [L]
                         RewriteRule ^/static/(.*) /path/to/static/$1 [L]
                         RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico /path/to/static/favicon.ico [L]
                         RewriteRule ^/robots.txt /path/to/static/robots.txt [L]
                         RewriteRule ^(.*) http://localhost:2209$1 [P]

      </VirtualHost>
  ```

If I set RequestHeader set REMOTE_USER "username" the application opens on the corresponding user session.

To see the value of REMOTE_USER I use the Firebug Firefox module to display the values of the http header + my application has a script that displays the value of variables passed to it.

I tested an almost identical Apache configuration on an index.php page that displays the values of server variables in a http request. The difference lies in the RewriteRules.

```
        <?PHP
                    foreach($_SERVER as $key_name => $key_value) {
                    print $key_name . " = " . $key_value . "<br>";

                    }
        ?>
```

In this case, I get a REMOTE_USER et HTTP_REMOTE_USER with a username value.

I don't understand where my problem lies.

Apache 2.2.31
RedHat 6.5

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 12):

do NOT use the following, because you will get into trouble with execution phases if the REMOTE_USER is set with a module like mod_authn_ntlm (ntlm with local computer, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/896861).

```
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.+)
RewriteRule . - [E=RU:%1]
RequestHeader set X-Remote-User %{RU}e
```

**instead use the following methods:**

```
RequestHeader set X-Remote-User expr=%{REMOTE_USER}
```

there is also a solution with mod_ssl

```
RequestHeader set X-Remote-User %{REMOTE_USER}s
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for Apache 2.4. The old style (RewriteCond etc.) works only in 2.2.

Comment: RequestHeader works for me too on 2.4! The RewriteRule was breaking subsequent requests between web services and I was getting Recursion errors! It's the correct answer.

Comment: The non-ssl version, `RequestHeader set X-Remote-User expr=%{REMOTE_USER}` only works on Apache 2.4.10+.

Comment: I find the example provided [here](https://gist.github.com/ollyg/5782078) more correct: `RequestHeader set X-Remote-User %{REMOTE_USER}e env=REMOTE_USER`

Comment: I'm very tempted to give a -1 for putting the wrong way prominently as the first code block. Despite the other text warning about it, it's easy for full stackoverflow devs to get in trouble. Sure, those of us who are careless probably deserve it, but still...

Comment: how to pass x-remote-user in the header. please suggest me some example.

Answer (score 2):

In Apache 2.2 server we gave below configuration. We have C# ASP.NET Core 2.1 application and in our HTTP Request header we get user name like below

```
   <LocationMatch ^/mylocation>
     AuthName "NTLM Authentication"
     NTLMAuth on
     NTLMAuthHelper "/usr/bin/ntlm_auth --helper-protocol=squid-2.5-ntlmssp"
     NTLMBasicAuthoritative on
     NTLMBasicRealm xxx_yy
     AuthType NTLM
     require valid-user
     RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.+)
     RewriteRule . - [E=RU:%1]
     RequestHeader set X-Remote-User %{RU}e

   </LocationMatch>
```

In our C# ASP.NET Core 2.1 application application we get below in HTTP Request Header

```
Key: X-Remote-User, Value=xxx_yy\abcdefg
```