# REMOTE_USER not always set in basic authentication when changing to running PHP as a CGI module

Tags: php, .htaccess, basic-authentication

My host provider just moved me to PHP 7.4 (at my request) and in the process changed PHP from running as an Apache module (now 2.4.52) to as CGI -- good from what I know.  My website uses Basic Authentication, and my code relies HEAVILY on `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` to get the username in tons of places.

In some cases at least (so far from what I've seen), that variable is NOT set, but instead `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER']` is.  In other places, there might be other `$_SERVER` vars that are set instead, tho I haven't seen them yet (I reverted to the old configuration for the time being, since this broke the site).   [BTW, a lot of this code is over 20 years old now.]

So my question: is there any way to force `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` to always be set with the username without having to modify all those places in my code?  Especially if there are some config settings that I could use?  I did see what looks to be a nice function to get the username in
[PHP get username from Basic Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55315832/php-get-username-from-basic-authorization)
but I'm hoping to find a way to avoid changing all that old code.  Or any other ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `CGIPassAuth On`? See my answer here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/66825530/369434

Comment: I tried that now and it didn't change anything AFAIK.  I put that in my .htaccess , and I still don't have PHP_AUTH_USER or PHP_AUTH_PW set.  I am using plain vanilla Basic Authentication.  Only the REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER gets set to the username   Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

> Only the `REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER` gets set to the username

You could perhaps auto-include a short PHP script that sets `REMOTE_USER` (from `REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER`) before your main script runs.

For example, set the `auto_prepend_file` in your `.user.ini` file in the root

```
auto_prepend_file=/path/to/fix-http-authentication.php
```

And then in your `fix-http-authentication.php` script, something like:

```
<?php
if (empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER'])) {
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER'];
}
```

Comment: up vote for using auto_prepend_file for a legacy site that does not have a common include.

Comment: OK, this does the trick.  One wrinkle is PHP_AUTH_USER was used in some pieces of code as the user, so I just embellished the fix-http-authentication.php script. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in your .htaccess after RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

That should set the REMOTE_USER environment variable when using CGI.

Comment: This works for some files but not all.  I'm unclear why it's not working for some, but $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] isn't getting set.  I'm investigating further; if you have any ideas, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to need to know more to be able to help further.  What else is in .htaccess that might prevent that line from executing for some pages.   Are you using a specific auth mod. SSL pages might need to be handled differently.  It might work better to set REMOTE_USER in conf file.  Perhaps more direct rewrite:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=REMOTE_USER:%1]

Comment: Are you sure you are putting this as the first rule after  RewriteEngine On, before some other rule can kick in an skip this one with [L] or something.

Comment: Is the path of the files where it's not working outside of the path where authorization is required?

Comment: I did NOT put it near the start of turning RewriteEngine on. I'll try putting in the conf file -- presently I was putting in lower level .htaccess files as I have various layers with different logins, e.g. user, admin, ...   And all files are in the authorization path, at least via symlinks if not really.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work at all... `REMOTE_USER` is parsed from the `Authorization` HTTP request, it shouldn't normally be set to the `Authorization` header. Normally, to pass the HTTP authorisation credentials through to PHP you would assign this header to the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` env var (which is "normally" what happens automatically in a non-CGI environment).

Comment: @MrWhite As I understand "normally" PHP parses the header to set these values in $_SERVER and passing the env var is a workaround for CGI.  I've seen RequestHeader set X-Remote-User expr=%{REMOTE_USER} used in .conf files as well so perhaps putting it in the header for PHP could do it.  Google found me this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33368653/how-do-i-set-remote-user-in-a-http-header